# Appending Integers to a multivalue parameter in a drill through report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a hierarchy of 4 reports to display increasingly granular data in charts. When the users click on a column in the main column chart, they go down one level. If they click on a column on the secondary chart on the same report, the report reloads with the new parameter selected. I am filtering the charts at the report level, but other items on the page are filtered at the dataset level. The parameter is pointing to integer ID field of the SQL data table.

I would like to add the new (integer) parameter to the bottom of the list, rather than wiping the current parameter out. What should I be passing to the report on the series action property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, found out how to do the task. It's messy, but it works. SSRS passes multivalue parameters to MSSQL as a string. This means that we can dispense with the niceties of dealing with integers and just jam together an array. The deliminator "%%" was chosen as this should never be a valid input, even in a string. The conversion to string on the field name is probably overkill.

=Split(Join(Parameters!ParameterName.Value,"%%") & "%%" & CSTR(Fields!FieldName.Value),"%%")